# Why can't I choose full screen mode in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, adobe-photoshop

I am using a trial version of Photoshop CS6, and I can't choose full screen mode. I am running OS X 10.9.

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Could it be because of Trial version? did you check that ?

Comment: On which OSX did you tried this ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Maybe, I don't know.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler OSX 10.9.1

Comment: You have to open a file first with PS. Then only the Fullscreen mode is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure there is a file opened first, if photoshop is "empty" the options are indeed grayed out even in the registered version of photoshop cs6.

Let me know if this fixed it

Comment: I will check this tip when I am using PS tomorrow.

Comment: can you elaborate what it means "grayed" out even in the registered version of psd 6? What should be done? How can I fix it?

Comment: In OP's image you see that several menu items are light gray (grayed out) those options are not available. in OP's case the solution was opening a file in photoshop